# How do you write a program that checks if the input follows a syntax?

Tags: python, syntax

Not sure if this is the right place to ask but I really need help with figuring out what I did wrong. I want to write a program that checks if my input follows a syntax.

These are the five functions for each rule of the syntax:

```
def molecule(q):      
    atom(q)               # molecule starts with an atom
    if q.peek() == "":    # if the next letter in the queue is none(end of line) dequeue the letter (end function)
        q.dequeue()
    else:                 # otherwise check if the atom is followed by a number
        number(q)

def atom(q):
    capital_letter(q)     # atom could be a single upper case letter
    if q.peek() == "":    # if it's the end of the line dequeue the letter (end the function)
        q.dequeue()
    else:                 # if it's not the end of the line, check if its a lowercase letter
        lowercase_letter(q)

def capital_letter(q):    # checks for capital letters
    letter = q.dequeue()
    if letter.isupper():
        return
    raise Syntaxerror("Missing capital letter")

def lowercase_letter(q):  # checks for lowercase letters
    letter = q.dequeue()
    if letter.islower():  
        return
    raise Syntaxerror("Expecting lowercase letter")

def number(q):            # checks if numbers are greater than 2
    letter = q.peek()
    if int(letter) >= 2:
        return
    raise Syntaxerror("Expecting numbers greater than 2")
```

However, when starting the program it doesn't fully follow the syntax. The inputs that work according to this program are for example: Aa2 and Ab
The output I get is (which is correct):

```
Follows the syntax
```

However, inputs formatted like these do not work(which are supposed to work): A, B12 and A3. The error I get for the input "A" is:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

For A3 and B12 I get:

```
Wrong! Expecting lowercase letter
```

I cannot see where I did wrong in the code and why it doesn't follow the syntax, thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an idea here - why not use regex. You can work it out if you like:

```
import re
num = '[0-9]'
let = '[a-z]'
LET = '[A-Z]'
print(re.match(re.compile(f'(^{LET})|(^{LET}{let})'), 'Ss'))
print(re.match(re.compile(f'(^{LET})|(^{LET}{let})'), 'sS'))
```

Answer (score 0):

first, a few thing about your `LinkedQueue`

- i think you're wrong about `dequeue`, it doesn't stop the function (and it shouldn't). that's why you get a `TypeError` with `A`: instead of stopping the function you send an empty queue to your `number` function.
- there are many repetitions in your code, and i think this code should belong to your `LinkedQueue` (all the `if peek=='': dequeue`)
- i don't think that adding an empty string in the end helps you at all

i don't know how to correct properly these problems, but `LinkedQueue` needs serious rethinking.

for the second error, your code contradicts your rules: the lowercase letter is optional but you make it mandatory. the `lowercase_letter` function shouldn't raise any error.

there is another problem with your `lowercase_letter` and `capital_letter` functions: you dequeue before the test. it goes silent now because you're raising an exception if the test fails, but in another context this behavior could be a source of unexpected results. suppose you remove the exception from `lowercase_letter` and your input is `A3`: you pop the number thinking it's a letter and now your stack is empty. no raise, so your code goes back and `molecule` calls `number` and throws again `TypeError`